# Data encryption algorithm which decrypts the data only once but need a different key to decrypt it again

Tags: security, encryption, public-key-encryption, drm

Is there any encryption algorithm already in which the encrypted data/file can be decrypted with the key only once, but it should re-encrypt the file so that a different key is needed to decrypt the same file again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not an algorithm per se -- once you have the key, the data is decrypted. But there are *techniques* to do that, and they typically pivot on one of the following:

- software obfuscation (you can Google keywords such as "software protection"), or
- hardware attack countermeasures (look up "Trusted Execution Environment" for example), or
- both at the same time.

This is for example pretty much what happens when you watch a Netflix movie on your PC which is connected to an HDMI TV: at a very simplified level, what happens is the movie is encrypted with a certain DRM key K1, it gets decrypted with K1 on the PC, and then immediately re-encrypted with a new HDCP key K2 on the way out to the TV (then the TV will decrypt it with the same HDCP key K2). Same story with Miracast and other similar protocols.

Answer (score 3):

No algorithm can do this.

Your own tools *could* do this, however...

Any competent attacker is going to

- Make a copy of the data
- Work with the copy
- Prefer to use their own tools, not whatever you provided

If they use your tool, where your own code could, indeed, re-encrypt the data, then they simply make a new copy of the original.

If they use their own tools, then they'd never re-encrypt the data in the first place.